# Vuejs2 get html from a div

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have the following code

```
<div>
 <div class="area">My area</div>
</div>
```

So by logging

```
console.log(this.$el)
```

it gives me the above raw html

Now i would like to get the html raw code between the div with class area

so i have tried

```
console.log(this.$el.getElementByClassName("area").innerHTML)
```

But the above is always undefined

How do i get the raw html code in a div

Comment: why is this offtopic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method as `getElementByClassName()` Instead there is `getElementsByClassName()` which returns a node list. So

```
console.log(this.$el.getElementsByClassName("area")[0].innerHTML)
```

Comment: thanks i see it works

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there:

```
console.log(this.$el.getElementByClassName("area").innerHTML)
```

Its `getElementsByClassName` on getElementByClassName, the `s` in Elements, you see!

Assuming you have fixed that but then also you will get `undefined` as the return value of `getElementsByClassName()` is a HTML Collection. Because it's a className based selector, and many elements can have same class name.

> The HTMLCollection interface represents a generic collection (array-like object similar to arguments) of elements (in document order) and offers methods and properties for selecting from the list

As It is similar to array, you can access it using index. so you can rewrite your code as

```
this.$el.getElementsByClassName("area")[index] // where index is 0,1,2,3....
```

Now you have the element's innerHTML by just accessing the innerHTML property of the element.

```
this.$el.getElementsByClassName("area")[index].innerHTML // where index is 0,1,2,3....
```

That's all it should work now.

I hope it helps.